# Insertar un carácter dentro de un archivo Python

Tags: python, archivo, formato

Estoy intentando insertar un salto de linea cada vez que se encuentra cierto dígito, en este caso una ',', sin tener que reemplazar o eliminar nada, solo para darle un mejor formato al archivo, estoy utilizando write cada vez que la encuentra, pero me añade el salto de linea al final & ocupo que lo de después de que encontró la coma dentro del mismo archivo, espero puedan ayudarme

```
file = open('C:\\Users\\ESantana\\Documents\\lineal.json', 'r+')
cont = 0
while True:
    caracter = file.read(1)
    print ("Caracter obtenido:", caracter)
    if caracter == ',':
        file.write('\n')
    if not caracter:
        print ("End of file")
        break
    cont += 1
file.close()
```

Comment: Hola Edwin, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español y enhorabuena por tu primera pregunta (que parece interesante). Visita el [tour] para aprender como funciona el sitio en general (y con ello ganar tu primera medalla). Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que veo que lo que pretendes es leer un json y añadirle retornos de carro tras las comas "para darle un mejor formato" como tú dices, te daré una solución mejor para ese problema.

Utiliza el módulo `json`, estándar de python, para leer el archivo (y así de paso verificas que esté correcto), y ese mismo módulo para volcarlo con un mejor formato, que no sólo consiste en retornos de carro, sino también en una mejor indentación cada vez que se abre una llave o corchete.

Sería así:

```
import json
entrada = "C:\\Users\\ESantana\\Documents\\lineal.json"
salida = "C:\\Users\\ESantana\\Documents\\formateado.json"
with open(entrada, "r") as fichero:
    datos = json.load(fichero)
with open(salida, "w") as fichero:
    json.dump(datos, fichero, indent=True)
```

Si quieres que modifique el mismo fichero, haz `salida=entrada`, pero no te lo recomiendo, al menos durante las pruebas.

### Actualización

Para añadir retornos de carro tras la coma, en caso de que el fichero no sea JSON válido y no pueda ser parseado adecuadamente, te recomiendo leer el contenido del fichero completo a una cadena, modificar la cadena en memoria, y volcar la nueva cadena a otro fichero. Esto es más sencillo que tratar de modificar un fichero mientras lo estás leyendo.

Por ejemplo:

```
entrada = "C:\\Users\\ESantana\\Documents\\lineal.json"
salida = "C:\\Users\\ESantana\\Documents\\formateado.json"

# Leer fichero completo
with open(entrada, "r") as fichero:
    datos = fichero.read()

# Añadir un retorno de carro tras cada coma
datos = datos.replaceI(",", ",\n")

# Volcar resultado a otro (o el mismo) fichero
with open(salida, "w") as fichero:
    fichero.write(datos)
```

Comment: De echo debo de comprobar si el json es correcto, al así como un logger, pero antes de encontrar el error debo darle formato(aunque este mal) & con el load si este esta mal, no me permite darle formato u,u, por eso ocupo hacerlo signo por signo

Comment: @EdwinSantanaBarcenas Mira mi actualización para una posible solución. También puedes usar expresiones regulares para mayor flexibilidad a la hora de elegir tras qué expresión quieres meter retornos de carro.

Comment: Gracias !!!!, me es de gran utilidad para lo que deseo hacer

Comment: Ok, aunque el formato que le estoy dando no es tan bueno, Ya que la tabulacion solo la toma para una sola linea, no para las que le siguen

Comment: Hola, disculpa tengo otra duda, digamos que quizás en un mensaje de json vengan ,{ o ] entre comillas " ", como puedo hacer para que las respete & no las reemplace? ya que he checado & si es mas sencillo trabajar el JSON como una cadena que como un archivo, espero puedas ayudarme, gracias

Comment: @EdwinSantanaBarcenas Tendrías que detectar si se han abierto comillas y cerrado después, pero entonces tendrías que tratar con el caso de que aparezcan comillas "escapadas" (con un `\"`), y poco a poco la cosa se puede ir complicando y podrías acabar encontrándote con que estás escribiendo casi un parser json. Para eso ¿por qué no usar uno ya escrito?  Mira [barely_json](https://github.com/torfsen/barely_json) que es capaz de decodificar json inválido o incompleto.

Comment: crees que barely me ayude a darle formato a un JSON corrompido?

Comment: @EdwinSantanaBarcenas No sé, nunca lo he usado, pero en principio es capaz de leer un JSON aunque esté mal (corrigiendo "sobre la marcha" lo que encuentra mal, siguiendo ciertos heurísticos), y después volcarlo bien. No sé si eso te valdrá. Prueba tú y nos lo cuentas :-)

Comment: nop jajajajajajaja cuando encuentra un error de llaves o corchetes, truena, mejor estoy haciendo mi propio embellecedor de JSONs O.O